# How to create a shared mode application with xwalkview?

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, crosswalk

I am working on hybrid app; I am using **xwalkview** library.  Thus, my APK size is almost 50mb; I just want to make multiple APKs for different architectures in parallel.  I'd like to try shared mode **xwalkview**, but I can't find any sample code for that.

Comment: Separated word stream into sentences; improved phrasing and misplaced modifiers.